# An isTrusted element is added into my array every time I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Todo list using Javascript and every time I refresh the page it stores a isTrusted: True in the array I have created to store the todo list items in the localStorage. If anybody can point out why this is happening it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

````
    ```javascript
function getTodos(todo) {
    //CHECK IF ANYTHING EXIST
    let todos;
    if (localStorage.getItem('todos') == null) {
        todos = [];
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }
    todos.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        //todo Div
        const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
        todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
        //create Li
        const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
        newTodo.innerText = todo;
        if (newTodo.innerText) {
            newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
            todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
            //CHECK MARK
            const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
            completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
            completedButton.classList.add("completed-btn");
            todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
            //TRASH BUTTON
            const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
            trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
            trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
            todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
            //APPEND TO LIST
            todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
        }
    });
}
        ```
````

Comment: When asking a question you need to provide a code

Comment: Post your code, so people who can help you can see what the problem is. You might get downvoted if you don't post proper question, and a new community member like you could lose the abiilty to post questions. Thanks. And welcome!

Comment: `isTrusted` is a property of event object. It looks like you send off the event object itself, rather than actual data, to your save-to-array logic.

Comment: @NikeLepz oh man don’t scare ppl. He won’t lose ability to post questions. But yeah AresLo, you do need to post your actual code in order to receive a proper answer. Description like this is vague, cannot pinpoint problem.

Comment: @hackape You do. I was trying to scare him, just giving him a heads up. Because when I first joined the community, I posted some questions which got a downvote. I used to get one question per day right, but then it said 'You aren't posting good questions.' or something like that for a good week or two.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everybody, in hindsight I should've added my code but I was confused by the instructions so I thought maybe I could do without it. However, I will keep your advice in mind for next time.

Comment: @hackape and could you answer my latest question which starts with 'Getting around...' lol.

Comment:  So you got rate-limited. I didn’t know they actually do that.